# JQuery droppable out event is not fired sometimes draggable with cursorAt

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

Sometimes JQuery droppable out event not fired when draggable has param cursorAd (before start dragging draggable moves out of droppable to set cursor position like in cursorAd).

For example (try to drag it by right bottom corner):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min-1.5.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min-1.8.9.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dg1" style="z-index:1;border:1px solid red;width:100px;height:50px;position:absolute;">draggable</div>
        <div id="dp1" style="border:1px solid green;width:100px;height:50px;position:absolute; top:100px;left:100px;">droppable</div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#dg1').draggable({
                cursorAt:{
                    left:20,
                    top:20
            }
        });
        $('#dp1').droppable({
            drop:function(){
                console.log('drop event');
            },
            out:function(){
                console.log('out event');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Just add tolerance `touch` to droppable

```
tolerance:"touch"
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/amarsingh/c46m20mq/)

> By default `tolerance` is set to `intersect`
>
> **"intersect"**: *Draggable overlaps the droppable at least 50% in both
>   directions.*
>
> We need to make it `touch` as per you requirement.
>
> **"touch"**: *Draggable overlaps the droppable any amount.*

Comment: It's more difucult to drop out draggable from droppable without firing out event with tolerance:"touch" but problem is not solved

Comment: @Mikhail :  drop event and out event is getting always . now what ?can you explain me what you exactly require.

Comment: First drag draggable like in this picture http://oi66.tinypic.com/6qe7pi.jpg . After this manipulation put droppable by right bottom corner and try to move it right and down. I want to catch moment when draggable leaves droppable.